# Removing an hyperlink from a woocommerce subscriptions email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

In my WooCommerce web shop, I am using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin.

I am trying to remove the hyperlink from a woocommerce email template:

[image: screenshot]

I don't see how I can do this from the template below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

There are no **`href`** in the code below, in order to remove said link.

How can I remove this hyperlink?

Thanks

Comment: There are some very strong indication that you're in the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the template located in the your subscription plugin: 
**`woocommerce-subscriptions/templates/email/subscriptions-info.php`** 
to your active chlid theme folder (or active theme folder): 
**`your-theme/woocommerce/email/subscriptions-info.php`**

**To understand WooCommerce templates:** 
[**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Once done you can change the code in this template at line 27 from here:

```
            <td class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:left;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( ( $is_admin_email ) ? wcs_get_edit_post_link( $subscription->get_id() ) : $subscription->get_view_order_url() ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf( esc_html_x( '#%s', 'subscription number in email table. (eg: #106)', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), esc_html( $subscription->get_order_number() ) ); ?></a></td>
```

Replacing by this:

```
            <td class="td" scope="row" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo sprintf( esc_html_x( '#%s', 'subscription number in email table. (eg: #106)', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), esc_html( $subscription->get_order_number() ) ); ?></td>
```

This is tested and works on WooCommerce 3+